router-outlet Cannot read properties of null angular 18
after updating angular 17 to 18, appeared in the console log  'router-outlet' is not a known element.
I have updated the Angular version from version 12 and I have never had problems
app.components.ts
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

app.module.ts
@NgModule({ declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PrivateContainerComponent,
    LogisticaComponent,
    ProductionComponent,
    AdministrationComponent,
    EstadisticasComponent,
    SecurityComponent,
    PublicContainerComponent,
    EvaluacionesComponent,
    ExtranjerosComponent
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent], imports: [BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RoutingModule,
    NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule,
    PdfViewerModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ColorPickerModule,
    OverlayModule,
    NgIdleKeepaliveModule.forRoot(),
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
        timeOut: 5000,
        preventDuplicates: true
    }),
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    VgCoreModule, VgControlsModule, VgOverlayPlayModule, VgBufferingModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
        config: {
            tokenGetter: getAccessToken
        }
    })], providers: [
    ToastrService,
    MenuService,
    DatePipe,
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-CL', },
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
] })
  export class AppModule {

constructor() {

}

app-routing.ts
  `export const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
path: 'public',
component: PublicContainerComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/features/login-lazy.module').then(m => m.LoginLazyModule),
  }
],
 },
 { path: 'login', component: MainLoginComponent },
 {
path: 'home',
component: PrivateContainerComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'produccion',
    component: ProductionComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/produccion/facturas-lazy.module').then(m => m.FacturasLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/produccion/logistica-lazy.module').then(m => m.LogisticaLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/produccion/personal-lazy.module').then(m => m.PersonalLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/produccion/gestion-produccion-lazy.module').then(m => m.GestionProduccionLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/produccion/personal-mantenedores-lazy.module').then(m => m.PersonalMantenedoresLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'miasistencia',
        component: CalendarioAsistenciaComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'administracion',
    component: AdministrationComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/administracion/logistica-admin-lazy.module').then(m => m.LogisticaAdminLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/administracion/aprobaciongg-lazy.module').then(m => m.AprobacionGGLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/administracion/facturas-admin-lazy.module').then(m => m.FacturasAdminLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/administracion/personal-admin-lazy.module').then(m => m.PersonalAdminLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/administracion/documentos-lazy.module').then(m => m.DocumentosLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'miasistencia',
        component: CalendarioAsistenciaComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'seguridad',
    component: SecurityComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/seguridad/usuarios-lazy.module').then(m => m.UsuariosLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/seguridad/sistema-lazy.module').then(m => m.SistemaLazyModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'miasistencia',
        component: CalendarioAsistenciaComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'evaluacion',
    component: EvaluacionesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/evaluaciones/evaluaciones- 
  lazy.module').then(m => m.EvaluacionesLazyModule),
      },
    ],
  },   
  {
    path: 'extranjeros',
    component: ExtranjerosComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          () => import('../app/features/extranjeros/extranjeros-lazy.module').then(m => m.ExtranjerosLazyModule),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'miasistencia',
    component: CalendarioAsistenciaComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'switch',
    component: SwitchComponent,
  },
],
  },

 { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/public/userlogin' },
 ];

 @NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: false 
 })], // .forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true })

exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class RoutingModule { }`
after compiling it, stays stuck on the main screen, not recognizing router-outlet (cannot read properties of null in console log)

Please, provide more information. Code snippets of your route settings, etc.
